# WebStorm 10 v Dreamweaver library Items

Tags: dreamweaver, webstorm

When managing large sites its useful in Dreamweaver to create library items which are snippets of HTML, usual headers or footers, that once embedded in a file can be updated and those changes are propagated throughout the site pages. Is there anything similar with WebStorm 10? I know there is File and Code Templates and #parse directives but that seems to be only insert into a new file... Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: No. WebStorm does not support Dreamweaver-like templates.

Comment: Yea I think the nearest is the Live Template feature...